# 2006 Scion XB window sometimes works sometimes doesn't

Tags: toyota, repair, power-windows, window, scion

My 2006 Scion XB driver side window is having some problems. Sometimes the window works perfectly fine going up and down. Other times when we roll the window down, it does not come up for the next 5 minutes. Does anyone have an idea of what the problem is here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most electric window motors have thermal cut outs on them. When used, heat will build up in the motor. If they get too hot, the cut out comes into play and keeps the motor from moving so as to not damage the motor. When the motor sits for a period of time, the heat is dissipated and the motor is allowed to work once again. This may be what's happening to your motor. It could be because its getting worn out. It could also be because the slides/mechanicals are not allowing the window to move as freely, which would mean the motor would have to work harder, and thus it creates more heat. Or, it could be a combination of the two (which is my guess).

My suggestion to you is, be prepared to replace the motor. You'll want to thoroughly clean the tracks, slides, pivot points when you do so. Sometimes you can get the motors already attached to new mechanicals, which is a little more expensive, but saves you a lot of time in the replacement process.